# MongoDB Device Sync - login() function never completes

Tags: android, mongodb, kotlin

I'm trying to use an anonymous authentication with a Device Sync. But I have troubles seeing any log in my logcat that will indicate some kind of an error. This is my code, the first log is triggered, however the second one after the login function, never does.

```
 viewModelScope.launch {
     Log.d("HomeViewModel", "Logging in")
     App.create(APP_ID).login(Credentials.anonymous())
     Log.d("HomeViewModel", "Completed")
}
```

Also I've needed to add this inside my gradle build file, or otherwise a compiler time error would appear:

```
packaging {
    resources {
        excludes += "/META-INF/**"
        excludes += "kotlin/annotation/annotation.kotlin_builtins"
        excludes += "kotlin/internal/internal.kotlin_builtins"
        excludes += "kotlin/collections/collections.kotlin_builtins"
        excludes += "kotlin/reflect/reflect.kotlin_builtins"
        excludes += "kotlin/ranges/ranges.kotlin_builtins"
        excludes += "kotlin/kotlin.kotlin_builtins"
        excludes += "kotlin/coroutines/coroutines.kotlin_builtins"
        excludes += "DebugProbesKt.bin"
    }
}

2 files found with path 'kotlin/annotation/annotation.kotlin_builtins'.
Adding a packagingOptions block may help, please refer to
https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/8.1/com/android/build/api/dsl/ResourcesPackagingOptions
for more information
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem indeed was in those exclude values. After removing them, everything worked out fine.